# URL Unknown Host Exception

Tags: java, url

I was trying this piece of code.Why would this give the **java.net.UnknownHostException: www.oracle.com**.The URl is pretty correct.Isn't it?

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Urlread {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: UnknownHost usually means incorrect url or your internet connection, isnt up, also check firewalls, some will completely block applications until you authorize them depending on your settings.

Comment: and check DNS settings on your operating system

Comment: i guess it should be `http://www.oracle.com`..remove `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were running on Android I would suggest you check the [INTERNET](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) permission, but since this doesn't seem to be the case, you should probably check your machine's internet access, firewall, proxy, DNS, etc. and of course the specifics for your application's internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. You just need to check the internet connection on the machine from where you are trying to run this code. I am able to successfully run the shared code and here is the snippet of output:

> var
>   _U = "undefined";    var g_HttpRelativeWebRoot = "/ocom/";    var SSContributor = false;    var SSForceContributor = false;    var
>   SSHideContributorUI = false;    var ssUrlPrefix = "/us/";    var
>   ssUrlType = "2";
>          var g_navNode_Path = new Array();
>          g_navNode_Path[0] = '8';    var g_ssSourceNodeId = "8";    var g_ssSourceSiteId = "ocomen";
>
> var g_strLanguageId = "en";
>
> ```
> <fragmentinstance  id="fragment3" fragmentid="ocomheader" library="server:OCOMHEADER">
>
> </fragmentinstance>
> <fragmentinstance  id="fragment4" fragmentid="ocomfooter" library="server:OCOMFOOTER">
>
> </fragmentinstance>
>   <fragmentinstance  id="fragment5" fragmentid="sitecatalyst-ocom-standard"
> ```
>
> library="server:SITECATALYST-OCOM-STANDARD">
>
> ```
>   </fragmentinstance>
>   <fragmentinstance  id="fragment6" fragmentid="ocomhp-commonassets" library="server:OCOMHP-COMMONASSETS">
>
>   </fragmentinstance>
>   <fragmentinstance  id="fragment7" fragmentid="ATGChat" library="server:ATG_CHAT">
>
>   </fragmentinstance>
>   <fragmentinstance  id="fragment8" fragmentid="UniversalSiteStudioManager"
> ```
>
> library="server:UNIVERSAL_SITE_STUDIO_MANAGER">
>
> ```
>      </ssinfo>   </script>
> ```
>
> Oracle | Hardware
>   and Software, Engineered to Work Together
>
> ```
>       <!--SS_END_SNIPPET(fragment1,head_tags)--> <!--
> ```
>
> SS_BEGIN_SNIPPET(fragment6,ocomhp-commonassets)-->
>                                      .menu-otn {display:none;}
>
> var atg_fName = "";     var atg_lName = "";     var
>   atg_eMail = "";   var atg_company = "";   //If User is logged in  if
>   (USER.guid) {         //Read user properties from cookie object USER
>         atg_fName = USER.firstname;         atg_lName = USER.lastname;      atg_eMail
>   = USER.username;
>
> ```
>   //Get cookie value ORA_WWW_PERSONALIZE and tokenize it to get value
> ```
>
> for cn (company name)         var personalizeCookie = (function(){            var
>   i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");          for
>   (i=0;i set to true
>                 }
>                 if(personalizeCookie != null && trustchk)       {           var cPair = "";             var cName = ""              var cValue = "";            var all_values =
>   personalizeCookie.split( '~' );           for (var i = 0; i <
>   all_values.length; i++ )          { 
>                 cPair = all_values[i].split( ':' ); 
>                 cName = cPair[0].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
>                 if (cName == "cn")
>                 { 
>                     cValue = unescape(cPair[1].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')); 
>                     break; 
>                 }           }       if (cValue.length != 0)             { 
>                 atg_company = cValue;           }       }       }); }
>
> var atg_country = "US";
>
> Oracle
>
> Select Country/Region
>
> Select
>   Country/Region
>
> Communities
>
> I am
>   a...
>
> I want to...
>
> Welcome     Account     Sign Out
>   Sign In/Register for Account     Help
>
> #### Products and Services
>
> #### Solutions
>
> #### Downloads
>
> #### Store
>
> #### Support
>
> #### Training
>
> #### Partners
>
> #### About
>
> #### Oracle
>   Technology Network
>
> #### Oracle Database
>   12*c*
>
> Plug Into the Cloud
>
> #### Oracle OpenWorld
>
> Register now
>
> #### Oracle
>   Cloud Application Foundation
>
> View the Webcast
>
> #### Big Data
>
> Making the big data
>   transformation
>
> ## Introducing Oracle Database 12*c*
>
> ### Get
>   a firsthand look at the only database designed for the
>   cloud. Join us at Oracle Technology Day.
>
> Find an Event Near You
>
> #### Plug Into the Cloud
>
> Mark Hurd and Andy Mendelsohn join Tom
>   Kyte to show how Oracle helps you tap into the benefits
>   of the cloud.
>
> Watch
>   the Webcast
>
> ## Register for Oracle OpenWorld 2013
>
> ### Meet
>   new peers, make the right connections, 
>  build your
>   community.
>
> Register now
>
> #### Make the Future Java at JavaOne
>
> Go to
>   registration
>
> ## Announcing
>   Oracle Cloud Application Foundation
>
> ### Deliver next-generation
>   applications with Oracle WebLogic Server.
>
> Register for the July 31st Webcast
>
> #### Extreme Performance with the Highest
>   Availability</nobr></h3>
>
> Learn more about the Oracle SuperCluster
>   T5-8</p> Find
>   out more</a></div> </div> </div>-->
>
> ## Transform Your Business With Big Data
>
> ### IT
>   strategies to capture, store, and manage growing volumes of
>   data.
>
> Learn more
>      A Big Data
>   Conversation
>
> Join Oracle Big Data Strategist Paul Sonderegger
>   and MIT Principal Research Scientist Andrew McAfee as
>   they discuss big data.
>
> Register for the July
>   30th Webcast
>
> ## Transform Your Business With Oracle Cloud
>
> Plan
>   Effectively
>
> - Enterprise
>     Resource Planning
> - Planning and
>     Budgeting
> - Financial
>     Reporting
>
> Support Customers
>
> - Customer
>     Service and Support
>
> Empower People
>
> - Human
>     Capital Management
> - Talent
>     Management
> - Talent
>     Management for SMB
>
> Get Social
>
> Social
>   Network
>
> Social
>   Marketing
>
> Social Engagement and Monitoring

Comment: I guess the problem lies in my using a proxy.How should i go about that?

Comment: @JohnSnow See if this sample helps: 
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("10.0.0.1", 8080));
conn = new URL(urlString).openConnection(proxy);